# Unable to find element with xpath == "//*[text()[contains(.,' "+ word + " ')]]"

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, sapui5

I had used sapui5 with xml view and java project, using Selenium 1.82 for automated testing.

xml code like this

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
  <Panel expanded="true" expandable="true" width="auto">
    <headerToolbar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Title text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_BASIC_INFO}" />
      </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <content>
      <f:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12" editable="true">
        <f:content>
            <VBox>
                <CheckBox id="SameWithInsured" text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_SAME_WITH_INSURED}" groupName="holderstatus1" selected="{searchModel>/d/SamewithInsured}" select="changeSameWithInsured"/>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" indent="L3 M3 S3"></l:GridData>
                </layoutData>
            </VBox>
          <Label text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_IDENTIFICATION}" />
          <VBox>
            <RadioButton id="PHPerson" text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_INDIVIDUAL}" enabled="{ path: '/d/SamewithInsured', model: 'searchModel', formatter: '.isPHDEditEnabled'}" groupName="holderstatus" selected="{= ${searchModel>/d/Person}===true}" select="clearRelation"/>
          </VBox>
          <VBox>
            <RadioButton id="PHLegalEntity" text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_CORPORATION}" enabled="{ path: '/d/SamewithInsured', model: 'searchModel', formatter: '.isLegalEntityEnabled'}" groupName="holderstatus" selected="{=${searchModel>/d/LegalEntity}===true}" select="clearRelation"/>
          </VBox>
          <Label text="{i18n>POLICY_HOLDER_INFO_RELATIONSHIP}"/>
          <Select id="relationSelect" width="100%" selectedKey="{searchModel>/d/RelationshipKey}" enabled="{ path: '/d/SamewithInsured', model: 'searchModel', formatter: '.isPHDEditEnabled'}" change="relationSelectChange">
            <items>
              <core:Item key="1" text="{i18n>POLICYHOLDER_BASICINFO_RELATION_BLANK}" />
              <core:Item key="2" text="{i18n>POLICYHOLDER_BASICINFO_RELATION_ELF}" enabled="{=${searchModel>/d/LegalEntity}===false}"/>
              <core:Item key="3" text="{i18n>POLICYHOLDER_BASICINFO_RELATION_SPOUSE}" enabled="{=${searchModel>/d/LegalEntity}===false}"/>
            </items>
          </Select>
        </f:content>
      </f:SimpleForm>
     </content>
  </Panel>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

My test script is(driver have been instanced)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dirver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + word + "')]]"))));
e.click;
```

I also tried

```
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//core:FragmentDefinition/Panel/content/f:SimpleForm/f:content/Select/items/core:Item[contains(.,'" + word +"')]"))));
```

got org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //core:FragmentDefinition/Panel/content/f:SimpleForm/f:content/Select/items/core:Item[contains(.,'配偶')] because of the following error:
Error: Namespace prefix not declared: core
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Comment: Assuming this dirver is a typo. What is an example "Word" you wanted to locate in the above?

Comment: The word likes '配偶' or '父母'

Comment: I found 2 similar questions [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609690/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-read-chinese-on-xpath) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787862/character-encoding-issues-in-eclipse-for-java-using-webdriver). the second question might contain an answer for you

Comment: My machine also already setted JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.The test script is running fine before April 17 this year.But when I retested on May 3, it throwed exception.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try the following syntax for the xpath?

```
"//*[contains(text(), '"+word+"')]"
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[contains(text(), '配偶')]

Comment: I have already fixed this problem by using implicitly wait instead explicit wait. driver.manage().timeout().implicitly(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

I had already fix this issue by using implicitly wait instead of explicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```